# Unable to create an object of type '[DBContext's Name]'. For the different patterns supported at design time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm following one of Mosh Hamedani Course on ASP.NET MVC in Udemy.

I came across one error while designing my Database using code-first (Entity Framework).

At first, I got the error of **" No DbContext was found in assembly"**. After resolving this problem another one surged from nowhere.

The image below will show you the error found while adding a migration. I've already searched for the same error but in vain. I'm struggling for the past two hours but nothing is solved till now.

Please, someone, help me. Thanks[image]

> unable to create an object of type 'Vidly_Context'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

---

Similar problem after adding own DbContext constructor with (2) parameters. App was ok, but migrations stopped working.
Fixed by 1st updating EF (3.1.5 used for strange reason when working with 5) using info from [Dotnet tool @xspdf](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/58549046.html) and replacing mentioned constructor by method + hardcoded default connection string if not set.

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef

// following command show the most during migration build/run in cmd
// mind current dir is Migrations folder of (VS) startup project here
dotnet ef --startup-project ../ --verbose migrations add test
```

3.1.5 & context activation Error

```
The Entity Framework tools version '3.1.5' is older than that of the runtime '5.0.0'. Update the tools for the latest features and bug fixes.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider in assembly '...'...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
No static method 'CreateHostBuilder(string[])' was found on class 'Program'.
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext '...Context'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type '...Context'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate '...'. (my additional parameter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_4.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type '...Context'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Comment: have you read the given link ?

Comment: Yes, its now working. A piece of C# code was to be added to the Startup file

Comment: @OoMaRjOhUr you could add an answer showing what code you added to get this working and then accept that answer.  That might help someone in future.

Comment: Yes, why dont @OoMaRjOhUr add the answer so the rest can see it?

Comment: Try running the app in debug mode and see whether the application throws an exception before before  the dbcontext is injected into the di container. Had the same problem caused by the application throwing before "options.UseSqlServer(.)"..I hope this helps

Comment: in Program.cs add "var app = builder.Build();" this line after builder.Services.AddDbContex

Comment: Temporary re-register all services from AddSingleton and AddScoped to AddTransient. It Worked for me.

Comment: In my case, there was a service which I was adding to the app and was causing the error. The service didn't have any relation to db context. The name of the service was provided in the warning message, something like this:
```
Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SearchClient.Abstractions.IAvailiabilityClient....```
After I removed extension method for this service from the app, I was able to create migrations

Answer (score 144):

1- Make sure to set your web project as **Set as Startup Project**

2- In **Package Manager Console**, set your data access layer (if any) as a *default* project

3- Then run the command again

Comment: Worthwhile to mention that if you use Rider where you don't have a "Set as Startup Project" you can use --startup-project on the command

Comment: This causes the error "Your startup project 'Web' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design." So regarding separation of concerns, I don't want my Web project to know about EF.....

Comment: I had an entirely different problem resulting in the same error. It is very useful to run Add-Migration with -verbose flag so you can see why it fails to generate migration. In my case it was a missing empty constructor for DBContext.

Comment: Sometimes it can be the tooling out of date as well

Comment: @JHBonarius did you get any solution for that?

Comment: Passing the params --startup-project=Project.WebApi and --project=Project.Data worked for me

Comment: After a fresh clone, I got the more meaningful error: Your startup project 'Xyz.Job' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, just wanted to point out that the error message itself is not very intiuitive ..

Comment: Yes, having a Multiple Project Startup set up in VS causes this error.

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks

Comment: My case, Install the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design to the startup project. It resolved.

Comment: @JHBonarius I get faced this error too. Would you recommend any solution for this?

Answer (score 88):

The error message states that the context could not be created at design time. If you specify in the migration command the startup project with the --startup-project flag (or -s) you can help the command create the context instance at design time in a similar way to how it would be created at run time.

For example:

```
cd ./project_with_migrations_folder
dotnet ef --startup-project ../my_startup_project_path/ migrations add myMigration01
```

Comment: Updated. The second command is an example of a migrations command with the startup-project flag specified. Should work with any migrations command. IMO is a better approach than existing answers because it doesn't require changing your code

Comment: Adding `--startup-project` fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: This did it for me too.  My connection string is in my appsettings.json, which is in my main web api project, which is separate from my data project (where the dbcontext lives).  I was running dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate in my data project, and it was failing with the error reported in the original post.  Once I added --startup-project and the path to my main web api project, it worked.

Comment: `--startup-project` fixed the issue for me. --verbose flag helpful, if you need further information about the issue

Answer (score 53):

I ran into the same issue. OP mentioned they needed to add code to their Startup.cs.

On https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 there's the following code sample;

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        => services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

My code was missing the following in my ConfigureServices method;

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

After adding this for my database context the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 23):

I ran into this issue when using EF Core code-first migrations in a .NET Core 3 solution that contained both an MVC project and a Blazor project.

If I have the solution's startup project set to the Blazor project I get the error when using `add-migration`, but I don't if I have the startup project set to the MVC project.

From reading the [documentation page linked to by the error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) and comparing the code in the startup.cs files for both projects I'm not sure why that would be, but temporarily switching the startup project to the MVC project fixes it for me.

Comment: Could your issue have been caused by having a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` in the MVC project but not the Blazor project? I have found this to be the case in the past.

Comment: @PTD I've very belatedly just tried adding that reference, but it didn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 23):

I got this error because a comma was missing in my appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=Leonardo-Notebook;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
  }, // <- Comma missing here
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem than this. As a suggestion, make sure your program runs, or at least starts before trying to fix the "add-migrations" problem

Comment: same here. thanks... feeling stupid

Answer (score 13):

I got this error after placing my DbContext in a separate class library using `.NET Core 3.1`.

Final solution looked like this that picked up my connection string from my original applications `appsettings.json`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();

            var connectionString = configuration
                        .GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

            return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

I could then use this in my other project like this:

```
var applicationDbContextFactory = new ApplicationDbContextFactory();

using (var dbContext = applicationDbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(args))
{
    
}
```

Comment: so it is not possible to have a dbcontext and a connection string configured in a settings file in a class lib?

Comment: you are right. in my case i just comment line "new ConfigurationBuilder()..." and it work.

Answer (score 13):

It's not really an issue with the framework, it's how you built your application. For example, if you used DI and you had the WebApi (or the MVC project) separeted from your data access layer, this will occur to you because when you try to add a migration, you context cant find the connection string that you're trying to inject (this actually was my case).

A good explanation is found here on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/issues/1080#issuecomment-504665885):

> That's definitely not an app issue which is this scope of the issues in this repo, but
> I'll try to give you some guidance anyway.
>
> You get that error because to generate migrations you need either:
>
> 1. A DbContext with a default constructor (that is, a parameterless constructor)
> 2. Being able to get the DbContext from ApplicationServices (that is, Dependency Injection)
> 3. A design time factory that returns a properly configured DbContext.
>
> Since ApplicationDbContext constructor has a parameter, you have to use options 2 or 3. See the details in the article: https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation
>
> But option 2 (the one originally used) doesn't work any more, because the program startup was changed to improve logging.
>
> And, since there's no DesignTimeFactory for ApplicationDbContext you just won't be able to create migrations at this time.
>
> If you want to learn about this way for creating migrations you can:
>
> Create an ApplicationDbContextDesignTimeFactory, similar to CatalogContextDesignFactory > or IntegrationEventLogContextDesignTimeFactory, or
> Try with other microservice like Catalog.API, that already has its DesignTimeFactory.

Comment: Yes, this was my case. I added DI after migrations and DbContext became inaccessible on design time. Solved by making DbContext parametrless by moving options to the OnConfigiring method of DbContext

Answer (score 9):

In StartUp file ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddDbContextPool<contextName>(
                    options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("conString")));
```

Comment: I'm using exactly this, but still getting the error

Comment: it work for me! what is diffrent "AddDbContextPool" and "AddDbContext" ??

Answer (score 5):

this is one of the most nonsense issues you'd ever encounter with ASP.NET Core. I am not really sure about the course you mentioned but if your application is just like mine where presentation layer is segregated from data layer; make sure that you install the latest version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design on your presentation layer too "your startup project". It is required, and the error message says nothing about it.

Comment: Obscure it is. I went for this option and all was good - thanks.

Comment: Before getting the error above, I was getting an error saying that the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is needed in the API layer, so this is not the case anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a properly authenticated database server like Azure SQL DB, check whether you replace the `Password={your_password}` with your server password in your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I made the **appsettings.development.json** file mandatory but I didn't create the file. If you are not creating the enviroment specific setting file, set it as *optional: true*

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
```

But, it is important to note that the error **may not necessarily related to the DbContext and its configurations**. It could be some other error in your application startup which prevents the app from booting up so that the EF tooling can do the migration. As a mechanism to locate any other error in your project startup, you can add console message at various lines of your Startup. You can even inspect appsetting values like connectionstrings using console while trying to migrate.

```
 Console.WriteLine("I can see this because the app was able to proceed this far.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your startup project uses the ASP.NET Core Web Host or .NET Core Generic Host, the tools try to obtain the DbContext object from the application's service provider, otherwise you could create the DbContext from a design-time factory (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation).

Comment: have you really linked a freaking spanish version