# Can't create database EF Core C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Im trying to create my database after finnishing up my classes, getting error message
"Unable to create an object of type 'HamsterDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time"

```
public class HamsterDbContext : DbContext
{
    public HamsterDbContext(DbContextOptions<HamsterDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public virtual DbSet<Hamster> Hamsters { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Cage> Cages { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ExerciseArea> ExerciseArea { get; set; }
}
   
internal class DatabaseHelper
{
    public static HamsterDbContext NewContext()
    {
        const string host = "(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
        const string database = "HamsterDaycare";
        var connectionString = $"Data Source={host};Initial Catalog={database};Integrated Security=True;";

        var dbContextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<HamsterDbContext>();

        dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new HamsterDbContext(dbContextBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Looks like this, typing add-migration CreateDatabase, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post full exception with stack.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding but I have been studying for 6 months now so don't know all the fine words yet, but what do you mean with stack?

Comment: Every exception has stack trace, so I'm interesting in that information.

Comment: Hmm, ok. What I wrote here is what I can find, don't know how to find that stack trace :/

Comment: Maybe you're having a typo somewhere in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123853/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-dbcontexts-name-for-the-different-patte, this is mainly due to your database is not accessible

Comment: Perhaps! I just did this instead and it worked, but if you see somewhere in the code where it could be wrong, please let me know! protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=HamsterDaycare;Integrated Security=true");

Comment: You replaced "\\" by "\", that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your string connection. Instead **DataSource**, put **server**. Your ConnectionString must be this way:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "server=yourserver;database=yourdatabase;user=youruser;password=yourpassword"},
...
```

},

Comment: There's nothing to be fixed in the area of keywords. Please read the comments, it was a simple typo.

Comment: yeah, but if you reproduce in MySql Data, the error is generate. I'm work with 3.1

Comment: The question is about SQL Server and the problem is solved. No answer necessary. It's obvious that every database interaction start with a well-formed connection string as required by the database provider.