# Error while updating Migration created in an Asp.net Core MVC project - Equinox

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm testing a project with DDD concept called Equinox at this address:

[Equinox](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject)

The first thing I did was update the Migration (Update-Database) of the Equinox.Infra.Dat layer and it worked correctly:

[image]

When I update the Migration (Update-Database) of the Equinox.UI.Web layer, which will create from the Identity tables, I get an error:

[image]

What is wrong? Why does I get an error when updating the Migration?
Are there any wrong settings in this project?

It should work!

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using two different databases or just one? Perhaps this link can send you on the right path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123853/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-dbcontexts-name-for-the-different-patte

Comment: Hi @Örvar! The Project creates a localdb database automatically... In theory, it uses only one database.