# PostgreSql and EntityFramework Unable to create an object of type

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core

when I am trying to use this command `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

I am getting error like : `Unable to create an object of type 'BlogDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time etc...`

Also I tried this(`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`) solution but does not worked for me.

My BlogDbContext code :

```
public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogDbContext(DbContextOptions<BlogDbContext> options) : base (options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>();
    }
}
```

Also I added my App class. App class contains my Run function.

```
public class App
{
    public App()
    {
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        var connstr = "Host=localhost;Database=blog;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=mysecretpassword";
        services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(x => x.UseNpgsql(connstr).UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());
        var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        using (var ctx = provider.GetService<BlogDbContext>())
        {
            ctx.Add(new Blog());
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The part of the error message you omitted tells you what to do. Did you read the link?

Comment: Try adding an empty constructor to the DBContext class.

Comment: @AbdelkrimBournane that's not the only option, or the best. A better one would be to use a design-time factoryThe error message contains a link to [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) that explains all options. If the application used the generic host there wouldn't be any problem to begin with

Comment: @Mehmet if you build an ASP.NET Core application why are you creating a `ServiceCollection` explicitly instead of using ASP.NET Core's host? Why create this `App` class when `Program` in .NET 6 or Program and Startup in earlier versions do what you want?

Comment: Still not resolved

Comment: Does it useful to u ?

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: No I did it. By the way, your method not is a solution. I tried earlier that.

Comment: Please check this thread.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123853/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-dbcontexts-name-for-the-different-patte

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to your BlogDbContext and it will fix the issue. I found this issue and also add a feedback at Microsoft doc site.

```
public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    // add this method
    public BlogDbContext()
    {
    }
    public BlogDbContext(DbContextOptions<BlogDbContext> options) : base (options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me with the help of Jason Pan's answer is as follows

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() { }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // I had to add this if statement
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        }
    }

    public DbSet<YourModel> Models { get; set; }
}
```