# Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbcontext'. I run into this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I am following a Udemy course. I am getting the error in the title and I also took a screenshot of the error. Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbcontext'. For the different patterns supported at the design time

[Screenshot of visual studio Startup. cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD9jV.png)

[screenshot of visual studio Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP0a7.png)
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYDcT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Infer from your error screenshot that you have this error when migrating your database. You can follow the steps below to solve：

1. Make sure to set your web project as Set as Startup Project
2. In Package Manager Console, set your data access layer (if any) as a
   default project
3. Then run the command again

If you still have this error, there are some other solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123853/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-dbcontexts-name-for-the-different-patte), you can refer to it