# How to create DB using EF Core Code first in class library project

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have solution in which standalone class library project(without web API/MVC project) in .NET 6.  I have not added any start up project as web API or MVC. I have added models and DB Context class in that project like below.

```
public class Producer
{

    [Key]
    public int ProducerID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(254)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Product
    {

        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public int ProducerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(254)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Producer Producer { get; set;}
    }
```

In my DBContext class code is as below.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;
        private readonly IConfiguration _iConfig;
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options, IConfiguration iConfig) : base(options) {
            _connectionString = GetConnectionString(iConfig);
            _iConfig = iConfig;
        }

        public static string GetConnectionString(IConfiguration iConfig)
        {
            var dataSource = iConfig["db:serverName"];
            var port = iConfig["db:port"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port))
                dataSource += "," + port;

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new()
            {
                ["Data Source"] = dataSource,
                ["Initial Catalog"] = iConfig["db:initialCatalog"],
                ["User ID"] = iConfig["db:userId"],
                ["Password"] = iConfig["db:password"]
            };

            return builder.ConnectionString;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
                                              => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);

        public DbSet<Producer> Producers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }


    }
```

When I am running add-migration command I am getting an error as

> Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Approach 2 - I have done the same code using console app so that I can have start up project but error remains the same.

What am I missing here. Thank in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to create an object of type '\[DBContext's Name\]'. For the different patterns supported at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123853/unable-to-create-an-object-of-type-dbcontexts-name-for-the-different-patte)

Comment: It depends. Is there a runnable project in the solution?

Comment: @GuruStron no. Its only class library project

Comment: @RomanMarusyk no.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` for only class library and it should be installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` for migration command.

```
public class AppDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

dbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Shall I add separate class file for AppDbContextFactory code and clean the code in AppDbContext file??

Comment: you should create AppDbContextFactory so you have to move connectionString

Comment: I have created separated .cs file for this but still facing the same error.